# how to change css class with toggleClass for specific class detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some `div`s with same `.hour_slots_available` named class. and also contained some disabled divs with `.hour_slots_disabled` named class which are change with response from database.

Now I want to change these `.hour_slots_available` `div`s with `.slot_activated` class when I `click`.

But when I click these `.hour_slots_available` `div`s then its changed with `.slot_activated` but also changed those disabled divs with selected divs

Here is html code

```
<li><div id="12_01" class="hour_slots_available" ><span class="hour_tag">12:00 - 01:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="01_02"><span class="hour_tag">01:00 - 02:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="02_03"><span class="hour_tag">02:00 - 03:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="03_04"><span class="hour_tag">03:00 - 04:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="04_05"><span class="hour_tag">04:00 - 05:00</span></div></li>
```

and here is my jquery code

```
$(".hour_slots_available").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("slot_activated");
});
```

here is image of output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMQPx.png)

please guide me where i'm wrong..!

Comment: $(".hour_slots_available").click(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('hour_slots_disabled')) {
          return;
}
        $(this).toggleClass("slot_activated");
    });

Try this!

Comment: its working.. thanks a lot bro @KalpeshSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".hour_slots_available").not(".hour_slots_disabled").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("slot_activated");
});
```

Comment: That first one is working and Thanks for another solution :)